# JQM Change Select icon to Notext

Tags: jquery-mobile

In trying to keep website responsive I want to hide the text from a select menu when the screen is below a certain size.
I use something similar to remove button text.

```
function resizeBtn() {
    var activePage = $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage");
    if ($(window).width() <= 490) {
        $("#opt_user_btn.ui-btn-icon-left", activePage).toggleClass("ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-icon-left");
         $( "#storeselect", activePage ).selectmenu( "option", "iconpos", "notext" );
    } else {
        $("#opt_user_btn.ui-btn-icon-notext", activePage).toggleClass("ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-icon-notext");
        $( "#storeselect", activePage ).selectmenu( "option", "iconpos", "notext" );      
    }
}
```

And the html is along the lines of:

```
    <form><select name="storeselect" id="storeselect" data-native-menu="true" data-iconpos="left" onChange="this.form.submit();" >
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>
</form>
```

I've looked at [JQM info](http://api.jquerymobile.com/selectmenu/#option-iconpos) but not figured it out yet. Help would be appreciated. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Inspecting the select bar the text for the selected option is in a `span` tag. One solution is to add a class with `opacity:0` to the span

```
<div id="storeselect-button" class="ui-btn ui-icon-carat-d ui-btn-icon-left ui-corner-all ui-shadow"><span>Option 1</span><select name="storeselect" id="storeselect" data-native-menu="true" data-iconpos="left">
<option value="1">Option 1</option>
<option value="2">Option 2</option>
</select></div>
```

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/mjk0f0t7/

**Jquery**

```
    $(window).on('resize change', function () {
    if ($(window).width() <= 490) {
        $("#storeselect-button").find("span").addClass("noshow")
    } else {
        $("#storeselect-button").find("span").removeClass("noshow");
    }
});
```

**Css**

```
.noshow {
    opacity:0;
}
```

To hide or style the icon also

```
$("#storeselect").append('<style>.ui-btn-icon-left:after{opacity:0}</style>');
```

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/wuLccyda/

To add ui-btn-icon-notext class simply use addClass and refresh the select menu

```
 $(window).on('resize', function () {
    if ($(window).width() <= 490) {
     $("#storeselect").addClass("ui-btn-icon-notext")
         $('#storeselect').selectmenu('refresh', true);
            } else {
               $("#storeselect").removeClass("ui-btn-icon-notext")
               $('#storeselect').selectmenu('refresh', true);
            }
           });
```

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/ywp70xtc/

Comment: Hi @Tasos thanks. That may well work, I've tried the jsfiddle, I'll try it on the site.  However, it wasn't quite what I meant. I probably explained badly.  Is there/how would I use the class ui-btn-icon-notext.  If I initially set `data-iconpos="notext"`, it removes the text and reduced the button size. That's what I was thinking.

Comment: Documentation says `$( ".selector" ).selectmenu( "option", "iconpos", "left" );` but I still couldn't get that working.

Comment: @devsie you mean the one in the center?? if you want to remove that from view add ($("#storeselect").append('<style>.ui-btn-icon-notext:after{opacity:0}</style>');) -- demo http://jsfiddle.net/nxz2m08h/

Comment: I was thinking i'd need something like `$("#storeselect").selectmenu("option", "iconpos", "notext")`  Not sure what the "option" should be replaced with.

Comment: @devsie I cant get it to work like that using JQM options. I created a workaround using css --- http://jsfiddle.net/whu3jL7c/

Comment: thank you very much for taking the time to look at it for me.  I'll use that work around. It would be nice to know how to do it 'properly'. I felt tantalizing close. :)

Comment: @devsie i have no idea why those JQM methods don't work as intended. the workaround is even better, if you noticed the select window stays exactly the same size as the width of the largest option text. can u up-vote my answer. thanks